# Scilab: same legend size in multiple subplots

Tags: scilab

I want to have a multiplot in scilab with a separate legend in each subplot. What I get so far is this:

[image: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-25692291/Test.png.html]

I get that the Legend entity is a child of the axis entity of the figure entity. What I don't know is how to adjust the size so that all plots and all legends are the same width. I only see the entries for position etc. if I go for figure.children(1).children(1). How do I access the legend size? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know either how to change directly the size of the legend: it seems to me, that it is always automatically calculated based on the length of the text. But there is a solution to get equally sized plots: you can set the size of the plot by the `margins` property of the axes. The second number adjusts the size of the "empty" space on the right hand side:

```
x=1:0.1:6; //generate some data
y=[sin(x);sin(2*x)];

scf(0); clf(0);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot2d(x',y');
a=gca();  //get the current axes
a.margins=[0.05,0.2,0.125,0.125];  //set the margins
legend("y1","y2",-1,%T);

subplot(2,1,2);
plot2d(x',y');
a=gca();  //get the current axes
a.margins=[0.05,0.2,0.125,0.125];  //set the same margins to get equally sized plots
legend("y___1","y____2",-1,%T);
```

The help says:
A vector [margin_left,margin_right,margin_top,margin_bottom] specifying the margins portion for this axes. This vector is composed of numbers between [0 1] with default: [0.125 0.125 0.125 0.125]. These numbers are ratios relative to associated values of the axes_bounds property, which are width for margin_left and margin_right, and height for margin_top and margin_bottom.